# Help with a query not working with custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query

The query below is always returning the latest "news" post, not the latest "news" post with the taxonomy "sotm". I have verified the details of my custom taxonomy, name is "postCat" attached to post type "news", and there is a term "sotm" applied to the post I want to display. Can anyone point out what might be wrong?

```
    <?php
        $sotmArticle_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'news',
            'postCat' => 'sotm',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'posts_per_page' => 1
        ));
        if($sotmArticle_query->have_posts()){
            while($sotmArticle_query->have_posts()){ $sotmArticle_query->the_post();
    ?>
```

Comment: You can't just make up parameters. 'postCat' isn't valid - where did you find that?

Comment: postCat is the name of a custom taxonomy

Comment: Yes, but you can't just put it there - did you look at the wp_query codex page? See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    $sotmArticle_query = new WP_Query(
      array(
        'post_type' => 'news',
        'tax_query' => array(
                           array(
                                  'taxonomy' => 'postCat', 
                                  'field' => 'slug', 
                                  'terms' => 'sotm'
                           )
                       ),
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 1
     )
    );
    if($sotmArticle_query->have_posts()){
        while($sotmArticle_query->have_posts()){ $sotmArticle_query->the_post();
?>
```

Comment: Forehead meets palm, I should have known that, I've done this before, thanks.