# Custom taxonomy - query returns an error

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query, taxonomy

Web page in question: http://www.cambridgesca.org.uk/ExternalDirectory/searchdirectory/

Plug-in used: Search & Filter

Frequencies is a custom taxonomy. Code, as follows, inserted at the end of functions.php in the theme folder.

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_taxonomy_frequencies' );

function register_taxonomy_frequencies() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( 'Frequencies', 'frequencies' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Frequency', 'frequencies' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search Frequencies', 'frequencies' ),
        'popular_items' => _x( 'Popular Frequencies', 'frequencies' ),
        'all_items' => _x( 'All Frequencies', 'frequencies' ),
        'parent_item' => _x( 'Parent Frequency', 'frequencies' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Frequency:', 'frequencies' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Frequency', 'frequencies' ),
        'update_item' => _x( 'Update Frequency', 'frequencies' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Frequency', 'frequencies' ),
        'new_item_name' => _x( 'New Frequency', 'frequencies' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => _x( 'Separate frequencies with commas', 'frequencies' ),
        'add_or_remove_items' => _x( 'Add or remove Frequencies', 'frequencies' ),
        'choose_from_most_used' => _x( 'Choose from most used Frequencies', 'frequencies' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Frequencies', 'frequencies' ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_tagcloud' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,

        'rewrite' => true,
        'query_var' => true
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'frequencies', array('post'), $args );
}
```

"Frequencies" is hierarchical, "type of work" is not.

All posts have Frequency assigned.

If I search for Type of work + Frequency (weekly + hospitality), I get results (in this case, 2 posts).

If I search for Type of work ONLY (hospitality), I get results.

If I search for Frequency (weekly) I get an error message (probably 404).

I also noticed that post pages do not list Frequency in their meta data (post created, tags such and such). 
I do not know if the failed query has anything to do with the absent meta data.

**Could you please advise me what code I need to implement (and which file / location it needs to go into) to get the query working on custom taxonomy?**

EDIT:
Code for the Search & Filter plugin is available through github, as far as I can tell the most relevant part to troubleshoot this problem is https://github.com/rmorse/search-filter/blob/master/search-filter.php

Sadly, I am not a code-monkey; I can understand simple commands but I get lost when dealing with complex data.

Comment: What is your search query code?

Comment: I don't know where to find it, so I can't answer your question. I think this might be a solution [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60330/help-with-a-query-not-working-with-custom-taxonomy], but I don't know how to implement it, and whether I'd need to do it with every new taxonomy.

Comment: "If I search for..."-- _how_ are you searching?

Comment: Using the UI on this website [cambridgesca.org.uk/ExternalDirectory/searchdirectory/].
Weekly + hospitality's url is [http://www.cambridgesca.org.uk/ExternalDirectory/?tag=hospitality&frequencies=weekly-regular] and renders correct results. 
Weekly [http://www.cambridgesca.org.uk/ExternalDirectory/?frequencies=weekly-regular] or [http://www.cambridgesca.org.uk/ExternalDirectory/frequencies/weekly-regular/] renders 404

Comment: That is far from a Core supplied search form. I am pretty sure you are going to need to track down the code that processes that form.

Comment: I want to know why it works when I search for "weekly + hospitality" and "hospitality", but NOT when I search for weekly.

Comment: It recognises that the custom taxonomy exists and can use it as search term, but only when it's combined with another search term.

Comment: And I can't tell you that without seeing the code! Please [edit] the question to provide the necessary information or I will have to close it as "Too Localized"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting permalinks, as per [this thread](http://themeforest.net/forums/thread/wordpress-custom-taxonomy-help-404-page-not-found/76735), fixed this problem.

Visit Settings -> Permalinks -> Save current settings